# Constraint layout with child constraint layouts not expanding horizontally

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to build a rectangular view (spanning the width of the screen) which is split horizontally into three blocks, and I am doing so using a constraint layout. The left and right blocks have a specified width, but the centre block should expand to fit the remaining space. Because I require that the left-most block have a different background colour to the parent, I have grouped its children into another constraint layout. I have given the layout XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#10000000"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#50000000"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/jkl"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/def"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ghi"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/def" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- This should expand to fit the remainder of the screen width -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/jkl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/stu"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/abc">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mno"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:textColor="#a0000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pqr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:textColor="#a0000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mno" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/x"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/jkl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Unfortunately, the middle block does not expand to fit the remaining width of the screen. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong here?

---

**Edit:**

Based on Ben P.'s response it may be that the XML above is fine, but the layouts in which this layout is contained are at fault. I have therefore provided them below.

This layout XML is the parent of the XML above:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.Parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

This layout XML is the parent of the RecyclerView XML above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**Edit 2:**

As requested I've provided the complete code base:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Foo());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Foo.java:

```
public class Foo extends Fragment {
    private String[] mDataset;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public Foo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Foo.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Foo newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Foo fragment = new Foo();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        initDataset();
    }

    private void initDataset() {
        mDataset = new String[1];
        mDataset[0] = "Hello World";
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.foo_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new FooAdapter(mDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

FooAdapter.java:

```
public class FooAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FooAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mFoofoo;
        private TextView mBarbar;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mFoofoo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foofoo);
            mBarbar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.barbar);
        }

        public TextView getFoofoo() {
            return mFoo;
        }

        public TextView getBarbar() {
            return mBar;
        }
    }

    public FooAdapter(String[] mDataset) {
        this.mDataset = mDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public FooAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.bar, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FooAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String text = mDataset[position];
        holder.getBarbar().setText(text);
        holder.getFoofoo().setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eaff73"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/foo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8df78b"
    tools:context="com.example.Foo">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="#10000000"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backg"
        android:background="#50000000"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foofoo"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barbar"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="14dp"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:background="#ef0505"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="#a0000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/action"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/backg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I copy/paste your code into my IDE, it seems to work as desired. What makes you think the middle section is not expanding to fill the screen width?

Comment: It appears correctly in Android Studio but when I run it in a Google Pixel emulator using API 21 it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: The only change I made was to add a background color to the middle rectangle, and to change `@drawable/x` to a plus sign I had lying around. This is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/hYFfjTA.png

Comment: I should point out that not only does the middle block not expand, it does not appear at all.

Comment: Even on a Pixel (Api 21) emulator, it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/blDw2Oa.png

Comment: Very strange... This is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/Z4Jwl0D.png

Comment: Updated my answer with the parent views in case it helps.

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to figure this out without your entire source code. I just wrote a tiny app that uses my updated answer below as the itemView for a ViewHolder and displays in a RecyclerView and everything works great for me: http://i.imgur.com/pn748H5.png

Comment: @BenP. I've added the complete code now. I hope this helps! I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know why this works, but it does.

In `bar.xml`, replace your outer `ConstraintLayout`'s height with `wrap_content` (instead of `104dp`).

Also in `bar.xml`, replace your `ImageView`'s height with `104dp` (instead of `0dp`).

This has the net effect of keeping your layout's design the same... it just has the `ConstraintLayout`'s height defined by the `ImageView`'s height, instead of the other way around.

If I had to guess at why this makes a difference, I'd assume that there's some quirk in the way `LinearLayoutManager` measures its children, and that when it sees a fixed height it ignores the `match_parent` width. But that's wild speculation.

Comment: Wow... Like you I have no clue why this is the case, but thank you very much for figuring it out! What led you to believe that might be the issue in the first place?

Comment: I started with the fact that, if I added 100 views instead of 1 to your adapter, anything that scrolled into view laid out properly. That smells like a measurement problem, so I started looking at measurements. The way your square ImageView was defined (fixed width, stretching height, parent with the same height as the image width) smelled a little funky, so I changed it. Suddenly it worked.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! I suppose having the parent fit the child is better anyway since it's the children that will change design rather than the parent.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Here is a flat `ConstraintLayout` that does what I believe you want:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#33000000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        tools:text="line 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        tools:text="line 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        tools:text="line 3"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        tools:text="line 4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:text="button"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And what it looks like:

[image]

---

### Original

This does not strictly answer the question (since as far as I can tell, there is no problem with the posted layout), but...

I see no reason to implement this UI using `ConstraintLayout`. The benefit of `ConstraintLayout` is that it allows you to avoid nesting `ViewGroup`s inside your top-level `View`. But as your `ConstraintLayout` is written, you're still grouping your `TextView`s inside a mid-level `View`.

If you are not taking advantage of `ConstraintLayout`'s ability to do organization without nesting, I think it is a better idea to use a simpler top-level view. Here is your UI reimplemented with `LinearLayout`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#10000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="#50000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/def"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="line 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ghi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="line 2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/jkl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mno"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#a0000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="line 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pqr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#a0000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="line 2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I removed the constraint layout for the middle block (the one I wished to stretch), so now there's only one child constraint layout. (The middle text views still don't seem to stretch, however.) The only reason I require this child constraint layout for the left block is because I need to display an image behind its children. Is there a way to position a box beneath the text views or is this beyond the capabilities of the constraint layout?

Comment: You certainly can. Something like an `ImageView` with fixed width inside the `ConstraintLayout`, with top/left/bottom matching the parent. Then a `TextView` with fixed width with top/left matching the parent. Then another `TextView` with fixed width with left matching the parent and top matching the first `TextView`'s bottom. That should give you an image with two pieces of text on top of it. Then after that you can position your other `TextView`s to the left of the `ImageView`'s right side.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of what I mean above

Comment: Just tried it and it works great! Still the middle text views don't expand which is driving me crazy!