# Clickable area of recyclerview not 100% width until scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a screen for an android app where I need to add a click event to each row of recyclerview and it's working in parts.

The problem is that once the intent is loaded the clickable area is limited to the width of its the contents.

the clickable area works fine (at 100% width) only if the recyclerview row is completely hidden from the viewport after a scroll happen.

Bellow has a gif that illustrates my problem. Note that before scroll the clickable area is reduced to row content and after scroll the clickable area fills the row.

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/wGvqa5Z.gif" width="150" style="width:150px; border:1px solid #000;" />
```

**active_catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="viniciusdesouza.com.br.barbearia.CatalogActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_catalog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_catalog" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="viniciusdesouza.com.br.barbearia.CatalogActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_catalog">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_catalog_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**catalog_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_catalog_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_catalog_item_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**CatalogAdapter.java**

```
public class CatalogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatalogAdapter.ViewHolderCatalog> {
    private List<CatalogItem> catalog;

    private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener;

    public CatalogAdapter (List<CatalogItem> catalog) {
        this.catalog = catalog;
    }

    @Override
    public CatalogAdapter.ViewHolderCatalog onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolderCatalog viewHolderCatalog = new ViewHolderCatalog(view);

        return viewHolderCatalog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CatalogAdapter.ViewHolderCatalog holder, final int position) {

        if ( (catalog != null) && (catalog.size() > 0)) {
            CatalogItem item = catalog.get(position);

            holder.txtItemName.setText(item.name);
            holder.txtItemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(item.price));

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    listener.onRecyclerViewItemClicked(position, -1);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return catalog.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolderCatalog extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtItemName;
        public TextView txtItemPrice;

        public ViewHolderCatalog(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_catalog_item_name);
            txtItemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_catalog_item_price);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Custom created method for Setting the item click listener for the items and items with in items
     * @param listener OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener
     */
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

**CatalogActivity.java**

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener { 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_catalog);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // back button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        recyclerViewCatalog = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_catalog_list);
        recyclerViewCatalog.setHasFixedSize(true);

        dbConnect();

        catalogRepository = new CatalogRepository(databaseHandler);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        catalog = catalogRepository.all();

        recyclerViewCatalog.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        catalogAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(catalog);

        mDividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(
                recyclerViewCatalog.getContext(),
                linearLayoutManager.getOrientation()
        );
        recyclerViewCatalog.addItemDecoration(mDividerItemDecoration);

        recyclerViewCatalog.setAdapter(catalogAdapter);
        catalogAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRecyclerViewItemClicked(int position, int id)
    {
        // do something with item clicked
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Out of curiosity, in your catalog_item.xml, if you add an id to the root linear layout and then set the onClickListener to that layout instead of the itemview, do you face the same issue? (Don't forget to add clickable='false' to the 2 textviews so the clicks will pass through to the base layout)

Comment: @Silmarilos After change the problem/bug still persistis.. anyway thanks for your comment

Comment: One other idea, in your content_catalog.xml file, Replace the base ConstraintLayout with a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout and try that setup. I'm curious if the issue is related to the app:layout_behavior tag.

Comment: @Silmarilos After replace ConstraintLayout  with LinearLayout everything is working fine! Please make this comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has to do with your ConstraintLayout in your content_catalog.xml file.

A similar issue is happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154427/constraint-layout-with-child-constraint-layouts-not-expanding-horizontally), so to fix it, try simply replacing it with something else like a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and it should resolve the issue of the view not expanding until after scrolling re-renders it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your ViewHolderCatalog class like below

```
public static class ViewHolderCatalog extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView txtItemName;
        public TextView txtItemPrice;

        public ViewHolderCatalog(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_catalog_item_name);
            txtItemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_catalog_item_price);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), “You clicked your your recycler view item”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: you are forgetting to set itemView. setOnClickListener(this) in the constructor of ViewHolder